# KSH for generating 'n' of rows for a table dynamically : Issue with if else statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

I need to generate billion of records in a text file for table loading purpose.

My destination table defination is:

```
CREATE  TABLE txnrecords12(
  txnno int, 
  txndate string, 
  custno int, 
  amount double, 
  category string, 
  product string, 
  city string, 
  state string, 
  spendby string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

For the purpose of generating data my code is:

```
############!/bin/sh
####### Create file dynamically
 if [ ! -d hero_work ]
then
    mkdir hero_work
fi
TEMPDIR=$HOME/hero_work
cd $TEMPDIR
touch $TEMPDIR/big_data_file_$$
echo $"string1\n",printf "string1\n",printf "string1\n">>big_data_file_$$
####################################
### Create data file dynamically####
####################################
 if [ ! -d hero_work ]
then
    mkdir hero_work
fi
TEMPDIR=$HOME/hero_work
cd $TEMPDIR
touch $TEMPDIR/big_data_file_$$
n1='
'
state_factor=$1
category_factor=$2
city_factor=$3
product_factor=$4
hiphen="-"
comma=","
### Write Table Columns Below
Col1="Txnno"
Col2="Txndate"
Col3="Custno"
Col4="Amount"
Col5="Category"
Col6="Product"
Col7="City"
Col8="State"
Col9="Spend_by"
####### Randomvariable declarations
rand1_Date_d="01"
rand2_Date_m="01"
rand5_Date_year="1999"
rand3_Transaction="0014"
rand4_cust_no="01155"
rand6_amount_no="0000"
######Column related variable declaration
var1_col1_txnno=0
var2_col2_txndate=0
var3_col3_custno=0
var4_col4_amount=0
var5_col5_category=0
var6_col6_product=0
var7_col7_city=0
var8_col8_state=0
var9_col9_spendby=0
write_value=${var1_col1_txnno}${comma}${var2_col2_txndate}${comma}${var3_col3_custno}${comma}${var4_col4_amount}${comma}${var5_col5_category}${comma}${var6_col6_product}${comma}${var7_col7_city}${comma}${var8_col8_state}${comma}${var9_col9_spendby}
Column_list=$Col1${comma}Col2${comma}$Col3${comma}$Col4${comma}$Col5${comma}$Col6${comma}$Col7${comma}$Col8${comma}$Col9
echo "$Column_list">big_data_file_$$
#####
####### Array of States
State[0]="UP"
State[1]="MP"
State[2]="Punjab"
State[3]="Delhi"
State[4]="WB"

### Array of Cities
City[0]="ABC"
City[1]="BCD"
City[2]="KJL"
City[3]="CGL"
City[4]="PPL"
#### Array of Products
Product[0]="ICECREAM"
Product[1]="Wheat"
Product[2]="CLOTHES"
Produt[3]="Laptop"
Product[4]="Bags"
Product[5]="Books"
#### Array of Categories
Category[0]="Foods"
Category[1]="Wearings"
Category[2]="Electronics"
###########3 Loop variables were initialized below 

var_state_loop=0
var_city_loop=0
var_category_loop=0
var_product_loop=0
while (( var_state_loop -le $state_factor  ))
do
  if[ $var_state_loop -le 4 ]
   then
       echo "State loop part starts here.."
       $var8_col8_state=${State[$var_state_loop]}
   else
       echo "State loop part ends here.."
      while((var_city_loop -le ${city_factor} ))
      do
        echo "City Loop starts here"
        if[ $var_city_loop -le 4 ]
         then
         $var7_col7_city=${City[$var_city_loop]}
        else
         echo "City Loop ends here"
         while((var_category_loop -le ${category_factor}))
         do
          echo "Category loop started from here"
           if[ $var_category_loop -le 3 ]
           then
           $var5_col5_category=${Category[$var_category_loop]}
           else
           echo"Category loop ended"
            while((var_product_loop -le 6))
            do
             if [ $var_product_loop -le 6 ]
             then
             $var6_col6_product=${Product[$var_product_loop]}  
             $var1_col1_txnno=${var8_col8_state}${var7_col7_city}${var5_col5_category}${var6_col6_product}${rand3_Transaction}
                while((rand5_Date_year -le 2016))
                 do
                 echo "starting date writing"
             if[ ${rand1_Date_d} -le 31 -a ${rand2_Date_m} -le 12 ]
              then
               $var2_col2_txndate=${rand1_Date_d}${hiphen}${rand2_Date_m}${hiphen}${rand5_Date_year}
             else
               echo "Date part completed"
                ((ran5_Date_year+=1)))
               done
               $var3_col3_custno=${var8_col8_state}${var7_col7_city}${var5_col5_category}${var6_col6_product}${rand4_cust_no}
              $var4_col4_amount=${rand6_amount_no}
              $var9_col9_spendby=${var3_col3_custno}${hiphen}${var7_col7_city}
             echo "The product loop finished for one product" 
write_value=${var1_col1_txnno}${comma}${var2_col2_txndate}${comma}${var3_col3_custno}${comma}${var4_col4_amount}${comma}${var5_col5_category}${comma}${var6_col6_product}${comma}${var7_col7_city}${comma}${var8_col8_state}${comma}${var9_col9_spendby}
echo ${write_value}>>big_data_file_$$
                ##### Product end variable declaration
        ((rand3_Transaction+=1))
        ((rand6_amount_no+=212)) 
                ((var_product_loop+=1))       
            done
             ((var_category+=1))
         done
             ((var_city_loop+=1))
     done      
  ((var_state_loop+=1))
done
```

When I am running the code the following error I am getting every time

```
line 94: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
biggun.ksh: line 94: `  then'
```

Comment: I'm not going to wade through your code (and I haven't used ksh in years) but I suspect your problem is `if[` (`[` is a test operator - not just punctuation)

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: please double check the while (( syntax - you could change it to while [

Comment: @jai_s please try to correct it since code is getting inside while loop

Comment: It appears to be an elementary syntax error (repeated throughout your script): you need whitespace to separate the keyword `if` from the test operator `[` - which should have been apparent if you'd bothered to test a minimal example such as `if[ 1 -le 2 ]; then echo "yes"; fi` instead of dumping your whole script on us.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks its a very good suggestion I will try it and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Some errors found:

1. The shebang must be #!/bin/sh. All the `#` are a syntax error.
2. Lines 15-21 are exactly equal to lines 4-11 (remove them).
3. Line 58 missing `$` in `Col2` var for `Column_list=`
4. Line 59, the `echo "$Column_list">big_data_file_$$` will erase all information previously written to `big_data_file$$`. Change to `>>`.
5. Line 93, 103, 112, 124 the `if[` should be changed to `if [`.
6. Line 114, the `echo"Category` must have an space: `echo "Category`.
7. Line 129, there are three closing `)`, remove one.
8. Line 129, the (( )) construct is not valid in sh (your shebang).
9. Missing multiple closing `fi` (at least 5) and maybe a `done`.

I got tired. Test your code, clean it up, do your homework.